# How to set already existing field as a foreign key to another table?

Tags: django, models

A have two model tables which contains data.

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #some other fields
    other_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

And the second class

```
class B(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #some other fields
```

Now I want field `A.other_id` to become a `ForeignKey` related to `field B.id`.
I cannot use SQL. I know it is supposed to be something like:

```
b = models.ForeignKey(B, db_column="other_id")
```

but it seems to not work.

Comment: i think you need put your real code, and steps you try with error you have, more details ==> faster and more correct answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) option?

You can do:

```
 b = models.ForeignKey(B, to_field="other_id")
```

However, the catch is that field `other_id` must satisfy `unique=True`.